# Check numeric expression (linear) is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, validation

There are many ways to check string valid or not using regex expression and using match/test match accordingly.
I am looking to check whether the expression containing alphabets(a-b), operators (+,-,/,*), only special characters like (')','(') and numerics (0-9) is valid or not

I have already tried for traditional methods pushing when the character is '(' and popping when ')' and checking the balanced parenthesis or not.
Code almost works for even operators but there are some cases where I am lacking behind.
The code provided might be right to some extent.

```
                      checkBalancedString(text){
                        let format = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
                        let expression = /[+-\/*]/
                        if(text.length <=2){
                            if(format.test(text[0])){
                            return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                         }
                        for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
                        let stringcheck=[]
                        if(text[i]== '('){
                            stringcheck.push(text[i])
                        }

                        switch(text[i]){
                            case ')':
                            if(!stringcheck.length){
                                return false;
                            }
                            stringcheck.pop();
                            break;
                        }
                        let checkalphaformat = format.test(text[i]);
                        if(checkalphaformat){
                        let nextChar =  format.test(text[i+1]);
                        let nexttonextChar = expression.test(text[i+2])
                            if(nextChar || nexttonextChar){
                            return false
                            }
                        }else{
                            let nextChar = format.test(text[i+1]);
                            if(!nextChar){
                            return false;
                            }
                            if(text[i+2]){
                            let nextChar = format.test(text[i+2])
                            if(!nextChar){
                                return false;
                            }
                            }
                        }

                        if(!stringcheck.length){
                            return true;
                        }
                        }

                        }
```

In short string should return valid where expression like:
(a+b), a+b, a/9, b*5 , (e-6*(d+e)), (a+b)/(c-d)
and expression like:
+, - ,-a,+a-, (a+, (a+v, e*)

The expression should be complete when every character is followed by the operator or parenthesis
either operator is followed by only characters
and parenthesis is followed by the only character.
There should be no operator together from the present index (front and behind)and no two characters together

Comment: One of your examples isn't linear. What's the exact need ?

Comment: To me, validate an expression in that way is an overkill. Have a look at this project: https://github.com/highfield/SimpleExpressionParser

Comment: @DenysSéguret I totally agree. I was not able to get the exact title so you can ignore , but from the examples its very clear and with the paragraph in the end I made it clear for what I am trying to achieve.
Full expression must be complete with balanced parenthesis and operators

Comment: @MarioVernari I can't say about the term 'overkill' here , but I am already aware about some string parser packages like https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser helping me out to some extent

Comment: @DenysSéguret editing the string tag might narrow down the search for this question, you already using methods of string in your solution.
It would be great if you can undo your edit

Comment: @shikhar Look at the [tag:string] tag. It's not the right one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is to check the validity of the formula more than to check a specific kind of formula.

Here's what I use in such a case:

```
// Return true if the passed string is a valid mathematical expression
//   taking as parameter a, b, c, etc.
// Examples:
//   2*a+b*b
//   (e-6*(d+e))
//   sin(a*PI + b.length) / ( round(d) - log(c) + +("Basse Qualité"===e) )
//   for (var i=0, total=0; i<10; i++) total += pow(a,i); return total
check = function(str){
    try {
        str = str.replace(/(^|[^\."'a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]\w+)\b/g, function(s, p, t){
            return t in Math ? p + "Math." + t : s;
        }); 
        if (!/\breturn\b/.test(str)) str = "return ("+str+")";
        var args = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        var f = Function.apply(Function, args.concat(str));
        f.apply(null, args); // if it works for args it should be ok for numbers...
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error while checking formula", e, str);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The basic ideas which should apply to your cases:

- try to instantiate a `Function` with your formula as body and `["a", "b", ...]` as argument names
- execute this function with a sample input (in my case `["a", "b", ...]`)

If you don't want such liberty as in my example, you may also test the character ranges (you don't have to allow `;` or ̀`,` if you don't want inline javascript)

Comment: can you please comment about the functionality of this function or any fiddle to check out this function with sample input

Comment: @shikhar I've added some comments. Is something still unclear ? It's used in one of my (not accessible) applications which lets users enter formulas used server side on big data computations using Nashorn

Comment: you explained more about the project here loll, anyway I am not getting the purpose of apply here

Comment: @shikhar the first `apply` calls the Function constructor. The second one checks the function doesn't crash during a simple execution

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, with little tweaks, I am able to achieve a valid formula(as you suggested)